# angular $http request in loop to update list data async

Tags: angularjs

I have list of ids [1,2,3,4], I need to make update with this ids and with the answer from my update I need to make UI update to displayed list.
I must update each row in my list async, once one id update finished I will make UI update for this row

my approach is to make for loop and to make $http request for each id

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < ids.length; i++){
     $http.get("api/update?Id=" + ids[i]).then(function (result) {
                            $scope.nodeUpdate = result;
    });
}

   $scope.$watch('nodeUpdate', function() {
      //update node result, the result will have node id+new data
   });
```

What do you think? This should work fine? 
Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: Why would you use a watch? Just call the function which "update node result" from the http callback function.

Comment: You are right, I can do it that way. Do you think this way I won't miss any result. What if 2 results are back at the same time?

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded. There is no way for two things to happen at the same time.

Comment: OK...so each promise that will back gets it's "own" update function?

Comment: When a promise is resolved, the callbacks passed to then() is called. So yes, the function(result) passed to then() will be called 4 times: once for each id.

Answer (score 1):

Better way to prevent code by creating anononyms function call stack.

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < ids.length; i++){
     (function()
       {
       $http.get("api/update?Id=" + id).then(function (result) {
            $scope.nodeUpdate = result;   
        });
      )(ids[i]);
}
```